can not use woocommerce rest api
I'm using a true consumer key and consumer secret but when I send a request, I face this error with 403 status code:
You don't have permission to access this resource
my python code is:
consumer_key = "ck_XXXXXXXXXXX" 
consumer_secret = "cs_XXXXXXXXXXXX" 



from woocommerce import API

domain = "nasimwebsite.ir"
wcapi = API(
    url = "http://" + domain,
    consumer_key = consumer_key,
    consumer_secret = consumer_secret,
    version = "wc/v3"
)
data = {"sale_price": str(100000)}

response = wcapi.put("products/" + '59', data) 
       
print(response.text)

